# Groovy Android plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android' or 'groovyx.android'

Tags: android, plugins, gradle, groovy

I see that many online samples on the groovy android plugin use:

```
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'
```

While the [github page](http://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin) for the plugin is using:

```
apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'
```

Is this just a name change or is there something more to it like different versions or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a name change as of Version 1.0.0

As it says in the [changelog](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/blob/9ed9d0ea5b284ff8f40ed2b853a6b6500b2d7c2f/CHANGELOG.md#100)

Comment: I get an error: **Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:1.0.0.**